# Which is best method storing and retrieving data for registration in php?

Tags: php, mysql

Any one please help me,

I am have doing one registration form, which have 50 fields and 3 steps for complete registration, i have confused, 
1) can i store all the fields in session or
2) each value store in database when steps complete and maintain one id that stored in database id in session, and retrieve values from database through that id

which is best one..

Comment: Use sessions, or you can also use hidden fields to store these values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends.

Storing intermediate data in a session, not in your database, will save precious server resources. This is important.

You also will not end up with a lot of half completed registrations because 3 pages, or 50 fields, will be too much for a majority of people, so they won't finish it.

On the other hand, you will never know how many people didn't finish your form if you don't store the intermediate data in your database.

If you use a database, your form could work even if you weren't allowed to store a cookie on the visitors computer.

So my idea is that storing the data in a database, is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

50 fields for registration is bit too much. I would consult my superior to divide it as:

Registration Basics:
   - Username
   - Password
   - Email

Registration Others (Picture, Passport# or similar): User will update his profile i.e. Part of this registration process at his ease or prompted to do so whenever one logins.

> Yes you can store all fields in Session, I would prefer cookies as you
>   can always read user cookies at a later time(set cookie expire time to
>   couple of days). Plus it'll ease burden from server.

You can use following SQL to return ID of the registration:

```
select last_insert_id()
```

Would recommend store as you go forward with your registration i.e. Insert Username, Password, Email initially, then use UPDATE statement to add information to the same person (or row in terms of database).

Hope this helps.